# How can i disable all systemd network configuration features and run my network initialize shell script?

Tags: networking, systemd

I have a network init script than

1. runs wpa_supplicant
2. runs dhcpcd

configureWifi.sh

```
pkill -9 wpa_supplicant
pkill -9 dhcpcd

wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhcpcd wlan0
```

i want to disable all systemd "network configuring" features
because their not working and make my system hangs on boot.
I just want to start the shell script.

My systemd unit description file looks like so:

/lib/systemd/system/goodwifi.service

```
[Unit]
description=Good wifi service, initializes wifi without networkmanger
[Service]
ExecStart=/root/configureWifi.sh
type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

```
# systemctl enable goodwifi
```

then after reboot wifi is not configured.
when i run this script by hand it works 100%.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your service might be running at the wrong time in the startup sequence. Try adding at least `After`and `Before`properties to configure that.
My suggestion is, let everything network start and then fire your service.
This was taken from `/etc/systemd/system/network.service` in an OpenSuse box

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager
Documentation=man:NetworkManager(8)
Wants=remote-fs.target network.target
After=network-pre.target dbus.service
Before=network.target
```

Also, it would be better if your script is located in an standard PATH directory, perhaps `/usr/local/sbin`.

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/configureWifi.sh
```

Check service start order with

```
systemctl list-dependencies network.service

network.service
● ├─dbus.socket
● ├─system.slice
● ├─network.target
● ├─remote-fs.target
● │ ├─iscsi.service
● │ └─remote-fs-pre.target
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─detect-part-label-duplicates.service
●   ├─dev-hugepages.mount
```

`journalctl -b0` should tell you how the script went.